# InfoPath Forms Library Multiple Item Creation Issue in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a Forms Library with a library InfoPath form. Everything is working fine until today a strange issue is observed and reported. Consider the below 2 scenarios in which the issue happens:

1. If I have items 121, 122, 123 and then I delete item 123 for some reason, then the next item that I create would be 124 ofcourse as I'm using the ID field to create my filename but this item upon editing would give me multiple items for each edit once submit button is clicked. But the strange part is if I leave 124 in it's last state for example after 2 edits now the latest ID would be 126 and create a new item 127, everything would be fine and each edit to 127 would update the same item.
2. The same behavior is exhibited for some of the old items but there is no real similarity between the items which have the issue and which don't and the problem is purely random.

The submit rules are pretty straight forward.

1. The current month is extracted using a substring formula from today().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4QdU.png)

2. The form year is calculated using the current year field which is extracted from today as well using the substring formula.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aRuj.png)

Based on the month form year is set to current year if the current month is before October.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADzxT.png)

Based on the month form year is set to current year +1 if the current month is after October.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX3zs.png)

3. Now I'm setting the Form ID to 1 if there are no items in the library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4E7K.png)

4. If there are items in the library and considering it is a new item with no Title then I'm setting the Form ID as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKGzN.png)

3. Now I'm setting the Form Title which I'm using as the filename in the form library submit with overwrite as yes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGi2P.png)

4. Finally Submitting the form.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYsoA.png)

I tried everything but could not figure out what is causing the issue. Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Suhas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the way the Title field is set in the workflow vs the way it is set in the form. Both were mismatching and hence every time the workflow runs, it is creating a new item for the same form which increments the ID.